# Error installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

This question has most likely been answered somewhere before, But I could not find the exact answer to my issue.

I'm, trying to install Linux Mint along side Windows 10 on my Lenovo ideapad 320s laptop. The installer keeps failing to detect any form of partitions. GParted is blank, I disabled Secure boot to no avail. I shrinked the Windows partition to make room for Linux

When I try to install it using the CD it states that there is not enough storage space.

Many Thanks

Comment: You used to have to shrink the Windows partition with a dedicated utility to have free space; or taking that in account when installing Windows.

Comment: I shrinked the partition already using the default Windows disk utility

Comment: (add that to the question...it is an important detail that you missed out)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to:

1. Update the UEFI BIOS from Windows
2. Disable secure boot (already done)
3. Enable legacy BIOS

Source: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ideapad-320/td-p/3849393

Subsequently you'll probably also need a newer kernel for touchpad support.